# Is there a SetImagingOpticsMode() function?

Tags: python, dm-script

I use the `Py_Microscope` class of [dm-script](/questions/tagged/dm-script) to control my microscope. This class provides a `CanGetImagingOpticsMode()`, a `GetImagingOpticsModes()` and a `GetImagingOpticsMode()` function. But I also need to set the imaging mode.

Is there a `SetImagingOpticsMode()`, either in the python environmnet or as a `dm-script` function?

---

According to [dmscripting.com](http://www.dmscripting.com/tutorial_microscope_commands.html) there was a `EMSetImagingOpticsMode()` function but is removed with GMS 2.x. And sice GMS is already on version 3 at the moment, I guess that it is still removed (at least it's not in the documentation).

I am using a JEOL microscope and I found the `JEOLcommand()` function. But this function also is not documented. And I found this in a very old script. I guess this is outdated too since it "uses serial communication" [[Save JEOL Microscope Configuration](http://www.dmscripting.com/save_jeol_microscope_configuration.htm)] which newer microscopes don't (as they say there).

And again, I came across the `EMSetImagingOpticsMode()` function in the documentation of the [VirtualTEM by Pavel Potapov, temdm.com](http://temdm.com/web/plugins/). There it is marked as "unofficial". But I think this information is also outdated. (If the timestamps are correct, the plugin is updated 2017 the last time and the documentation is from 2014.)

So is there any way to *set* the optics mode? Or do I have to do it manually?

Comment: There is no *reliable* way of settings modes for many micrscopes. Only few support this, and I don't know which. It is recommended to do it manually only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The script command
>
> `void EMSetImagingOpticsMode( String mode )`
>
> does still exist in GMS 3.
> The accordingly available string parameters could be found using:
>
> `EMGetImagingOpticsModes().TagGroupOpenBrowserWindow("",0)`
>
> Similarly, there exists the also not officially supported command:
>
> `void EMSetOperationMode( String mode )`

---

However, neither of the mode-setting commands is officially documented
as they do not work on all microscope systems and are not a supported feature.

Usage of the commands is "at one's own risk" and might also get GMS into a confused state, breaking proper behavior and requiring a software restart.

Comment: "[B]reaking proper behavior", that doesn't sound good :D I will give it a try. Otherwise I will just show a message to change the mode.